# EF Code first Eager loading and OrderBy problem

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, ef-code-first, eager-loading

I have two entities called Category and Product with 1:n relation.

I want to get a Category with its childs that childs be in order.

This is my linq:

```
 _db.Categories.Where(c => c.CategoryID == catID)
    .Include(c => c.Products.OrderBy(p => p.ProductID))
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

This query enforce with the below exception because of orderby.

> The Include path expression must refer
>   to a navigation property defined on
>   the type. Use dotted paths for
>   reference navigation properties and
>   the Select operator for collection
>   navigation properties. Parameter name:
>   path

Answer (score 6):

Eager loaded data cannot be ordered or filtered. That is linq-to-entities limitation and the only way how to order relations in the database is by using projection:

```
var data =  _db.Polls
               .Where(c => c.CategoryID == pollID)
               .Select(c => new 
                   {
                       Pool = c,
                       Products = c.Products.OrderBy(p => p.ProductID)
                   })
               .SingelOrDefault();
```

You can project to anonymous or custom type but you cannot project to mapped type (for example `Poll`).

Another way is dividing this to two queries and use explicit loading:

```
var poll = _db.Polls.SingleOrDefault(c => c.CategoryID == pollID);
_db.Entry(poll).Collection(c => c.Products)
               .Query()
               .OrderBy(p =>.ProductID)
               .Load();
```

Answer (score 2):

`Include` has to reference a navigation property, which means you can't include an `OrderBy()`. Instead of this:

```
_db.Categories
    .Where(c => c.CategoryID == catID)
    .Include(c => c.Products.OrderBy(p => p.ProductID))
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

...you'll have to use this:

```
_db.Categories
    .Where(c => c.CategoryID == catID)
    .Include(c => c.Products)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

...to access an ordered list of `Products` for each `Category`, you could add a property to `Category` like this:

```
class Category
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> OrderedProducts
    {
        get { return this.Products.OrderBy(p => p.ProductID); }
    }
}
```