# EF 6 - Include Why Do I not have linq choice?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am a bit confused on why I don't get linq.

```
context.Users.Include(x => x.Roles)
```

I can't do this I have to do     `context.Users.Include("Roles")`

Seems like other people can do it.

[EF Code first Eager loading and OrderBy problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595436/ef-code-first-eager-loading-and-orderby-problem)

Do I need to import something? Has something changed in EF 6(rc1)?

Comment: Have you add using System.Linq?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If you're using `DbContext`, the correct namespace to import is:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

This is the namespace that contains `DbExtensions` that provides the type-safe versions of the `.Include` method.